# Nature of perturbed state in perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I'm interested in the “nature” of the perturbed state in [perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29) in quantum physics.

The first order perturbed state is given by

$$ \psi^{(1)}_{n}=\Sigma_{m}a_{m}\psi^{(0)}_{m} ~, $$

where the *perturbed* state $\psi^{(1)}_{n}$ is expanded as a sum over *unperturbed* states $\psi^{(0)}_{m}$ (i.e., eigenstates of the *unperturbed* Hamiltonian).

Now as the Hamiltonian changes upon applying the perturbation, its basis should also change accordingly. My question is, why the basis does *not* change when we add a perturbation to the system?
More precisely, what is the justification for expanding the perturbed state as a sum of unperturbed states?

Comment: It seems there is misuse or misunderstanding of the word “basis”. As the _basis_ of the Hilbert space, one can use _any_ complete set of states. The thing that changes upon adding a perturbation, is the set of the _eigen-states_ of the Hamiltonian (not necessarily the basis of the Hilbert space). We use the same _basis_ before and after adding the perturbation: that basis is the eigen-states of the unperturbed Hamiltonian --- as described in the [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60354/76263) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the Hamiltonian is written as
$$
  H = H^{(0)} + V
$$
It is assumed that both $H^{(0)}$, the unperturbed hamiltonian, and $H$, the perturbed hamiltonian, are self-adjoint.  In particular, there is an orthonormal basis $\psi^{(0)}_m$ for the Hilbert space consisting of eigenvectors of $H^{(0)}$, and a an orthonormal basis $\psi_m$ consisting of eigenvectors of $H$.

One can choose to write any state $\psi$ in either basis.  In particular, one can choose to write the first order perturbed state in the basis $\psi^{(0)}_m$ of $H^{(0)}$ and then use this to derive lots of useful things.

**Addendum.** One thing I forgot to mention is why one would *want* to write the perturbed state in the unperturbed basis.  The simple, essential answer is that perturbation theory is so useful precisely because the unperturbed Hamiltonian can be easily diagonalized; namely it's eigenvectors and eigenvalues are known exactly, whereas those of the unperturbed Hamiltonian are not.

Answer (score 0):

A wavefunction is a complete description for a system where the basis states are all orthogonal. So if you think of a vector as a linear combination of the three basis vectors, any vector can be described by this method (including a different set of basis vectors). Similarly after a perturbation we can describe our new basis vectors as linear combinations of our old ones.